# Blender Rig - problem (Blender 3.4.0) - Bone changes mesh rotation

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

I am new to Blender and having some issues following tutorials along where the mesh is assigned to bones. I have created a mesh and an armature. Bones are working as expected. At this point I am supposed to be able to parent the mesh to the armature by selecting the mesh, shift selecting the armature and then Ctrl-P, Parent with empty groups. Then I should select portions of the mesh and assign to vertex groups. But the problem is when I assign different mesh parts to the bones it changes rotation of the mesh (Legs on screenshots).
[image]
[image]
[image]
For rigging i followed these tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkiWBSSuxLw&t=821s&ab_channel=Imphenzia
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0YOZHvGPR8&list=PL0tCPY3ApJrxrHmSXUkhlBWb_UgqLR75m&index=7&ab_channel=DaniArkadia-SurvivalRevivalGames
Can somebody please to explain the problem here? Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably need to change the Pole Angle value in the IK constraint, also make sure that the knees bend a bit forward in Edit mode

Comment: I think you're right! I had pole angle set to 0, but when i changed it to 90 leg returned to it supposed place :) Hope that was the only issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the *Pole Angle* value in the *IK* constraint, also make sure that the knees bend a bit forward in *Edit* mode.

Comment: Yes that is the way to solve the problem. Thank you very much! :)